# How to join/ merge two tables using character values?

Tags: r

I would like to combine two tables based on first name, last name, and year, and create a new binary variable indicating whether the row from table 1 was present in the 2nd table.

First table is a panel data set of some attributes of NBA players during a season:

```
   firstname<-c("Michael","Michael","Michael","Magic","Magic","Magic","Larry","Larry")
   lastname<-c("Jordan","Jordan","Jordan","Johnson","Johnson","Johnson","Bird","Bird")
   year<-c("1991","1992","1993","1991","1992","1993","1992","1992")

   season<-data.frame(firstname,lastname,year)


    firstname   lastname        year
  1 Michael      Jordan         1991
  2 Michael      Jordan         1992
  3 Michael      Jordan         1993
  4 Magic        Johnson        1991
  5 Magic        Johnson        1992
  6 Magic        Johnson        1993
  7 Larry        Bird           1992
  8 Larry        Bird           1992
```

The second data.frame is a panel data set of some attributes of NBA players selected to the All-Star game:

```
   firstname<-c("Michael","Michael","Michael","Magic","Magic","Magic")
   lastname<-c("Jordan","Jordan","Jordan","Johnson","Johnson","Johnson")
   year<-c("1991","1992","1993","1991","1992","1993")

    ALLSTARS<-data.frame(firstname,lastname,year)



     firstname  lastname    year
  1 Michael     Jordan    1991
  2 Michael     Jordan    1992
  3 Michael     Jordan    1993
  4 Magic       Johnson   1991
  5 Magic       Johnson   1992
  6 Magic       Johnson   1993
```

My desired result looks like:

```
  firstname lastname    year    allstars

   1    Michael Jordan  1991    1
   2    Michael Jordan  1992    1
   3    Michael Jordan  1993    1
   4    Magic   Johnson 1991    1
   5    Magic   Johnson 1992    1
   6    Magic   Johnson 1993    1
   7    Larry   Bird    1992    0
   8    Larry   Bird    1992    0
```

I tried to use a left join. But not sure whether that makes sense:

```
    test<-join(season, ALLSTARS, by =c("lastname","firstname","year") , type = "left", match = "all")
```

Comment: I would use `left_join` or `right_join` from the dplyr package as in David's answer.  But for fixing your code: it looks like you are using `join()` from the plyr package.  You were almost there, just preface your command with `ALLSTARS$allstars <- 1`.  Then do your join and convert the `NA` values to 0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: @ Sam Firke. That was just extraordinary! :) Thank you. Worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad it helped - I've written it up as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `join()` from the plyr package. You were almost there: just preface your command with `ALLSTARS$allstars <- 1`. Then do your join as it is written and finally convert the `NA` values to 0.  So:

```
ALLSTARS$allstars <- 1
test <- join(season, ALLSTARS, by =c("lastname","firstname","year") , type = "left", match = "all")
test$allstars[is.na(test$allstars)] <- 0
```

Result:

```
  firstname lastname year allstars
1   Michael   Jordan 1991        1
2   Michael   Jordan 1992        1
3   Michael   Jordan 1993        1
4     Magic  Johnson 1991        1
5     Magic  Johnson 1992        1
6     Magic  Johnson 1993        1
7     Larry     Bird 1992        0
8     Larry     Bird 1992        0
```

Though I personally would use `left_join` or `right_join` from the dplyr package, as in David's answer, instead of plyr's `join()`.  Also note that you don't actually need the `by` argument of `join()` in this case as by default the function will try to join on all fields with common names, which is what you want here.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple solution using `data.table` binary join which allows you to update a column by reference while joing

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(season), firstname, lastname, year)[ALLSTARS, allstars := 1L]
season
#    firstname lastname year allstars
# 1:     Larry     Bird 1992       NA
# 2:     Larry     Bird 1992       NA
# 3:     Magic  Johnson 1991        1
# 4:     Magic  Johnson 1992        1
# 5:     Magic  Johnson 1993        1
# 6:   Michael   Jordan 1991        1
# 7:   Michael   Jordan 1992        1
# 8:   Michael   Jordan 1993        1
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
ALLSTARS %>% 
  mutate(allstars = 1L) %>%
  right_join(., season)
#   firstname lastname year allstars
# 1   Michael   Jordan 1991        1
# 2   Michael   Jordan 1992        1
# 3   Michael   Jordan 1993        1
# 4     Magic  Johnson 1991        1
# 5     Magic  Johnson 1992        1
# 6     Magic  Johnson 1993        1
# 7     Larry     Bird 1992       NA
# 8     Larry     Bird 1992       NA
```

Comment: @ David, thank you so much! My example is somehow misleading. Are you referening in your example to the column `allstars` or table `ALLSTARS`

Comment: using the first advice I get: `Error in bmerge(i <- shallow(i), x, leftcols, rightcols, io <- haskey(i),  : 
  x.'firstname' is a character column being joined to i.'year' which is type 'integer'. Character columns must join to factor or character columns.`

Comment: I don't get these errors, but i'd suggest you use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating your data sets as in `season<-data.frame(firstname,lastname,year, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` and `ALLSTARS<-data.frame(firstname,lastname,year, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`. What is the `data.table` version you are using btw?

Comment: Its in the corresponding data types(`first/lastname=chr`) Hmm ok thanx!! 1.9.4

Comment: I'm using the devel version (1.9.5) so it was probably fixed there.

Answer (score 2):

In base R:

```
ALLSTARS$allstars <- 1L
newdf <- merge(season, ALLSTARS, by=c('firstname', 'lastname', 'year'), all.x=TRUE)
newdf$allstars[is.na(newdf$allstars)] <- 0L 
newdf
```

Or one I like for a different approach:

```
season$allstars <- (apply(season, 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse='')) %in%
apply(ALLSTARS, 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse='')))+0L
# 
#   firstname lastname year allstars
# 1   Michael   Jordan 1991        1
# 2   Michael   Jordan 1992        1
# 3   Michael   Jordan 1993        1
# 4     Magic  Johnson 1991        1
# 5     Magic  Johnson 1992        1
# 6     Magic  Johnson 1993        1
# 7     Larry     Bird 1992        0
# 8     Larry     Bird 1992        0
```